# How to use Enterprise library and mysql database with c# 4.0?

Tags: .net, mysql, c#-4.0, enterprise-library

I am creating a web app using C# 4.0. Mysql is being used as database, id columns that i have taken as char(38) in database while in object i have taken them as unique Identifier type but i am getting error, couldn't able to parse it. Other issue is how will i use stored procedure, for connectivity i am using enterprise library 5.0 and it is giving error no such function or procedure exist. Please guide me thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i manage to solve my problem, actually when i have took char(38) as id column and parsing it in GUID type then I was getting it as string type, but i have changed it to char(36) and its works perfectly. 
Enterprise library issue is due to a bug with mysql, i have passed my database name with uppercase letter in the connection string, it must be in lower case letter. http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61249